# alamofire Swift: Can't download image to location specified by user

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, alamofire

I am struggling to download a url to a user specified path using the Alamofire library

```
let savePanel = NSSavePanel()
        savePanel.allowedFileTypes = ["jpg","gif","png","webp"]
        let result = savePanel.runModal()
        if ( result == NSFileHandlingPanelCancelButton) {
            print("cancelled")
            return
        }

        if let fileUrl:NSURL = savePanel.URL {

            Alamofire.download(.GET, imageUrl, destination: fileUrl)

        }
```

The above code seems to give me an error: 
[image]

Has anyone got any pointers on how to resolve this to help user download image to file location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one its work for me :-

```
let manager = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance              
manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 600

var localPath: NSURL?
manager.download(.GET, savePanel.URL,destination: { (temporaryURL, response) in
             //Create directory
             let documentsPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0])
             let myDirectory = documentsPath.URLByAppendingPathComponent("MyDirectory")
             do {
                  try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(logsPath.path!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                } catch let error as NSError {
                     NSLog("Unable to create directory \(error.debugDescription)")
               }
                let directoryURL = myDirectory
                let pathComponent = response.suggestedFilename

                localPath = directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent!)
                return localPath!
            })
                .response { (request, response, _, error) in
                    print(response)
                    if error != nil {
                        print("REQUEST: \(request)")
                        print("RESPONSE: \(response)")
                    }
                    if localPath != nil {
                         print("from url Downloaded file to \(localPath!)")
                    }

            }
```

Comment: How do I get that - to the path specified by the user?

Comment: You want download file on specific location right just mini i will edit answer.

Comment: Please review my edit code . "MyDirectory" is your directory.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work - as it doesn't seem to take the path given by the  SavePanel

Comment: OK I worked it out - the SavePanel returns a full path including the Filename and extension so by appending url component- I was turning the filename into the folder.

If I set local path = savepanel.url it works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116768/discussion-between-mobile-bloke-and-mitul-marsonia).

Answer (score 0):

You should use something along the lines of ::

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/image/png")
     .responseImage { response in
         debugPrint(response)

         print(response.request)
         print(response.response)
         debugPrint(response.result)

         if let image = response.result.value {
             print("image downloaded: \(image)")
         }
     }
```

[This is on reference page here.](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage)

And to use just import `AlamofireImage`

and add this to your podFile :

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 2.0'
```

I would highly recommend using Alamofire Image as it is a specific-purpose library, as a component of Alamofire for downloading images.

Comment: How would that let me save to a url specified by SavePanel?